# Unresolved reference: RECTANGLE_HEIGHT_250

Tags: android, ads

I am trying to integrate the Facebook ads into my android app! But During the implementation, i am having the following error! Please try to help me! Thanks

Error "Unresolved reference: RECTANGLE_HEIGHT_250"

val adView = AdView(context, "IMG_16_9_APP_INSTALL#YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID", AdSize.RECTANGLE_HEIGHT_250)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added facebook's AdSize

```
com.facebook.ads.AdSize.RECTANGLE_HEIGHT_250
```

because AdSize is also available in google's `gms.ads` package may be by mistake you imported them

Comment: Thank you very much. You were right!  The issue is Solved!